# ¿Cómo rehacer un cambio que deshice en Vim?

Tags: vim, vi

Estaba trabajando con Vim e hice un cambio. Sin embargo, por error apreté <kbd>u</kbd> y eso provocó que se deshiciera.

¿Existe alguna forma de "rehacer" un cambio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sí, debes usar la siguiente combinación en el modo de comandos:

<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd>

O, en el modo "normal" puedes ejecutar:

```
:redo
```